# Net core 3.1 mvc app deploy as windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-services

I have made a simple application in net core 3.1 using mvc and razor pages and I want to deploy it in windows 10. I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 with Visual Studio Code. I have deployed the application as a Self-contained deployment (SCD) running

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 --self-contained True
```

Then, copy the folder to a Windows machine. If I double click the .exe, everything runs perfect. But when I create a windows service with

```
sc create RazService binPath= %~dp0Raz.exe
sc start RazService
sc config RazService start=auto
```

When running the app, it enters the home page. But when I navigate to another page that requires access to the database (SQLite), it cannot find it.
I tried to change the keys-values in the regedit  to change the root directory but it didn't work.
So What am i missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: You should configure logging in your application and save all exceptions (including unhandled) - then probably you will find what is wrong.

Comment: MVC app as Windows service made me kind of curious. How is this service suppose to behave?

Comment: @RoarS. When Windows start, the server runs and starts listening on a specific port.